# Can't re-reference `the_geom` when requesting CSV format in Carto

Tags: postgis, carto, sql

We're developing a reverse proxy sitting in front of Carto's API. When a user of our reverse proxy requests data, we'd like the geometry values to be returned as Well-Known Text. And our reverse proxy sits in front of an arbitrary number of tables/datasets, so we don't know the field names ahead of time (and I'd like to avoid a second HTTP request to find them out if possible, just for speed).

To accomplish this with the JSON format, we've been using:

`SELECT *, ST_AsText(the_geom) AS the_geom`

([example](http://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*,%20ST_AsText(the_geom)%20AS%20the_geom%20FROM%20%22incidents_part1_part2%22%20LIMIT%2010))

This works fine - it only outputs a single `the_geom` field. I'm not sure if this is a feature of Postgres or simply a "feature" of JSON (you can't have more than one property with the same name).

The problem is that it doesn't work when making the same query with `&format=csv` ([example](http://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*,%20ST_AsText(the_geom)%20AS%20the_geom%20FROM%20%22incidents_part1_part2%22%20LIMIT%2010&format=csv)). It throws the error:

`ERROR 1: ERROR:  column reference \"the_geom\" is ambiguous"`

Any advice on getting around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are getting `the_geom` twice. The first inside the `*`, and the second, as the new field you are creating on the fly. If you change the alias of this last field and use any other name but `the_geom` such as `the_geom_as_text`, the query would work. [Here](http://phl.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*,%20ST_AsText(the_geom)%20AS%20the_geom_as_text%20FROM%20%22incidents_part1_part2%22%20LIMIT%2010&format=csv) you have the working query.

Comment: Thanks, but it works fine when I query it as JSON. It's only when I add the `&format=csv` parameter to the URL that it throws an error. Could that point to another issue?

Comment: It could. The error is expected (it fails also with other formats). `json` most likely works because of a wrapped query where the second `the_geom` shadows the first one. But this is a not expected behaviour.